# How to see the boot progress messages (akin to dmesg) when booting LineageOS?

Tags: boot, lineageos

After the last OTA update my phone (OnePlus 3) seems to be stuck for about half an hour on the boot animation.

Since updates usually take ages to install, how do I know that the update process is stuck?

On my desktop I can always see `dmesg` message during the boot, and it is relatively easy to troubleshoot problems. Is there a tool that allows me to see the diagnostic messages while the phone is booting?

Comment: http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.liveboot

Answer (score 2):

Finally I've managed to do that without any 3rd party addons. The key is to get `boot.img`, and modify the file `default.prop` that is living in the root folder inside the `img-ramdisk.gz`:

You have to do three modifications:

1. `persist.sys.usb.config=none` -> `persist.sys.usb.config=mtp,adb`
2. `ro.secure=1` -> `ro.secure=0`
3. `ro.adb.secure=1` -> `ro.adb.secure=0`

You can get the `boot.img` if you extract the flash image with the OS you are currently using, or by extracting it from the device directly.

After that, the `adb logcat` **will** collect the live boot messages when you connect your laptop to the phone when it boots.

With adb secure on '1', it will give you 'unauthorized' message when you attempt to adb.

`ro.secure=0` allows adb to have root privileges (see more here https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/adb/daemon/main.cpp)

---

All credits go to the IRC users LuK1337 and razorloves from the LineageOS Discord/IRC channel.

Comment: Boot progress messages on Linux PC appear on kernel console or first virtual terminal. They start appearing from bootloader stage. But your proposed solution gets the logs on USB (not framebuffer) from a userspace daemon when at least kernel, `init`, `logd` and `adbd` are running. If a panic occurrs before this stage, you won't get any logs. So technically it's not "akin to dmesg". // `ro.secure=0` and `ro.adb.secure=0` work only on `debuggable` builds. So this solution won't work on any stock/`user` ROM. // `last_kmsg` and `pstore` are more certain ways to get persistent logs from last reboot